# 404 Error despite the file existing in directory

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, iis-8.5

I keep getting a 404 error when testing an application migration to a new server. The file exists in the root folder (it's a login page), the spelling in the URL is correct. I saw a few forums and posts here suggesting to add it to the default document in IIS but that also gives the 404 error. There is nothing blocking the file type either.

I saw some other suggestions saying to check to make sure the extension is right and not typed as part of the file name, but that also was no issue for me.

would anyone have any suggestions? I am out of ideas and seemingly tried all the solutions that I found on the internet with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It can be many things unfortunately.

I would try to create a simple test.html file with one word in it, like "Hello".

If you cannot load that page either then you have a routing issue. (wrong binding, some other website tries to handle the request, wrong port, maybe IIS redirect rule...)

If you can load it then there is an issue with something else, like application pool or http handlers, etc.

You could also turn on logging and see if it hits the server and if it does then what is happening.

Also, can you load other files in the directory?

Comment: it appears that nothing in the directory can be found.

Comment: Have you tried to turn on the IIS log to see if your query hits the website (or which website if you have more than one)?

Answer (score 1):

First check the file/folder permissions (properties->security->advanced (effective permissions might also help)) and if file has hidden attribute (hidden is to hide not to disable, as far as i remember). Read for Everyone user for example should be enough. Inherited permissions are real pain. Deny kicks in even if there are 20 allows.

Comment: Good suggestion! Everyone though has read or full control. I don't see anything mentioned about something being hidden.